# How to make models dynamic in my template angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a template with text box in my directive,on click of button(ADD) i am repeating the same directive 10 times so 10 times text box will come but ng-model will remain same for each text box and this i need to make dynamic so that on each repeat of template ng-model becomes different.
Problem is I am not able to create dynamic ng-model for text box to distinguish between the values entered so that I can access it in my controller.How to make model of text box dynamic.

```js
App.directive("configDirectives", function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, $attr) {
          console.log('Scope in directive : ' + scope);
          scope.add = function() {
            console.log("Inside directive value of satCount", satCount++);
            $newDirective = angular.element('<add-config></add-config>');
            element.append($newDirective);
            $compile($newDirective)(scope);
            console.log('Scope in directive : ' + scope);
          }
        }
      }).directive("addConfig", function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          template: '<div>{{scope.satCount}}' +
            '<input type="text" ng-model="x"/>' +
            '</div>',
          link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
            scope.remove = function() {
              element.remove();
            }
          }
        });
      <!-- Controller -->
      (function() {
        var self = null;
        var ConfigRuleClass = Class.extend({
          init: function($scope, configService) {
            self = this;
            self.$scope = $scope;
          },
          save: function() {
            console.log("values from parent configuration---");
            console.log("config1---", self.lstConfigs.name);
            console.log("Dynamic Filed Data" + self.dynamicConfigs);

          }
        });
        App.controller("ConfigRuleCntrl", ['$scope', 'configService', ConfigRuleClass]);
      })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="xx" data-ng-controller="ConfigRuleCntrl as y">
  <input type="text" ng-model="y.x" />
  <button data-ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <br>
  <button data-ng-click="y.save()">SAVE</button>
  <config-directives></config-directives>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create plnkr for your question?

Comment: How do you repeat textbox?

Comment: should be a ng-repeat that we are missing here?

Comment: on click of button(ADD) I am adding text box ,i.e on each click only once my template should be repeated.It is repeated using directive where I have written a add method which is called on click of add

Comment: can you post the code for the directive and the code for the `add()` function, since they seem to be the main pieces of code here.....

Comment: err never mind, it looks like you might have tried to include it, but didn't format it well, it's not actually showing up....

Comment: ok, so after editing the code to actually see what's going on, it's even more obvious that you aren't doing this the angular way.  I keep saying this on multiple questions; Angular is perfectly capable of dynamically managing the DOM on it's own, you don't need to create Directives to do things that the built-in features like `ng-repeat` already handle.  The angular way is to code against the Data, not the DOM.  This is definitely coding against the DOM.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1

Comment: see my answer to a *very* similar question yesterday:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312277/add-row-function-to-push-new-object-in-angular-ng-repeat/31312678#31312678

Comment: @Claies Yes I have added the code snippet,you can refer that above.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of 10 objects and use as source for ng-repeat.
 Objects would be like:

```
[
   { id:1 value:'' },
   { id:2 value:'' },
   ...
]
```

And the html:

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="entry in entries track by entry.id" ng-model="entry.value"></input>
```

I created an jsFiddle to show how it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/un1g3fao/2/

Comment: I can not use ng-repeat because on click I want to repeat my template only once,I need solution without the usage of ng-repeat .

Comment: Then you can simply only add 1 entry to the repeat source. Or if that is not appropriate please include a plunker to show your specific problem.

Comment: what if requirement is for 100 times I cant use ng-repeat on click only once my template should be repeated. Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: @satyendrakumar your comment here doesn't make sense.  What do you mean, your template should only be repeated once? your code is definitely showing you *trying* to repeat it multiple times....

Comment: I added a fiddel to show how it works, and to check if that is what you need. Can you please describe how the behaviour in the fiddle is different than your requirement?

Comment: @DenisThomas your fiddle is definitely the angular way to do things, but I think you have an error, since Add 1x adds 2, and Add 10x adds 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to create a dynamic Model on using input

Working Code Clck [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ALHQtkjiUDzZVtTfLIOR?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newObject[item.name]">
```

To maintain the previous data use copy

```
 var original = Data.data;
 $scope.newObject =angular.copy(original);
```

Comment: I agree with ur solution but I have to repeat my template on click and only once on each click and I have to maintain the previous data also.So I cant use ng-repeat.Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: you most certainly *can* use `ng-repeat`; put your data into an array, and each time you want to add a new row, add a new element to the array.  Angular will do the rest.